# Cmake Error: Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS)

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, freetype, sdl-ttf

I am using [SDL](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL), [SDL_image](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image) and [SDL_ttf](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf) ( they are added as submodules) for a small 2d game. When i am buiding the project with cmake it is giving me errors -
[I am getting these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSqXm.png)

but when i am removing sdl_ttf from the project then it is building correctly

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.2)

project(LunarLander VERSION 0.1.0)


add_subdirectory(vendor/SDL)
add_subdirectory(vendor/SDL_image)
add_subdirectory(vendor/SDL_ttf)


file(GLOB LL_SOURCE_FILES src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB LL_HEADER_FILES include/*.h)

add_executable(LunarLander ${LL_SOURCE_FILES} ${LL_HEADER_FILES})

set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT LunarLander)

target_include_directories(LunarLander PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
                                         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/SDL/include/
                                         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/SDL_image/
                     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/SDL_ttf/)

target_link_libraries(LunarLander SDL2 SDL2main SDL2_image SDL2_ttf)
```

The project is on github- [LunarLander-Clone](https://github.com/AbhayJoshi-Dev/LunarLander-Clone)

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: As you can guess from the error message, it is about missed **FreeType** library. It is clearly stated in [README](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/main/README.txt) for SDL_ttf library, that the library **requires FreeType**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev i know that but why SDl_ttf's CMakeLists.txt is not building freetype as freetype's source comes with it in external folder?

Comment: According to SDL_ttf's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt#L9), it uses shipped FreeType only when build for Android. On other platforms FreeType is expected to be already installed. If you want to ask about reasoning of such decision, then you need to ask specifically developers of SDL_ttf. Stack Overflow is not a place for questions which only developers can answer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So i have to install freetype to my system , then i am able to build this right ?  and Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, as stated in the README, you need to install FreeType before building SDL_ttf.

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem:**

> *Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS)*

**Solution:**

Open the SDL_ttf CMakeLists.txt file and find the following line:

```
set(vendored_default FALSE)
```

Then change it to be `TRUE` instead. CMake will now build freetype as a prerequisite to building the ttf library.

By default, the ttf library no longer ships with freetype and it must be manually added into the external folder and be told to be built. It seems the developers are of the opinion that you should be using a system wide package manager to get a pre-built version of freetype.